# Can't change policies of a project event though I am its owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have a project on Google Cloud called, let's say, "Orange Octangulars" under an organization "Acme corp". As I can see on https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam, I have the role "Owner" in "Orange Octangulars". I have also given myself the role "Project IAM Admin" just in case, so I have two roles in "Orange Octangulars". I am trying to allow external IPs for VM instances in "Orange Octangulars". I do so by going to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/orgpolicies/compute-vmExternalIpAccess (under the project "Orange Octangulars") and I want to press "Manage policy". Unfortunately, that button is greyed out and the error message, when I hover over it, says:

> You need permissions for this action.
> Required permission(s):
>
> **Orange Octangulars**
> All of orgpolicy.policies.create, orgpolicy.policies.delete, orgpolicy.policies.update, and orgpolicy.policy.get

What's up with that? I am an owner and a project IAM admin of the project. Why can't I manage this policy or any other policies for the project?

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned "Orange Octangulars" under an organization called "Acme corp”'. So [organizational policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/understanding-hierarchy?hl=en) is enabled on this project and this is why you are getting the reported error.

Run the following command:

```
$ gcloud projects describe Orange Octangulars
```

With the result of the above command,you can take the `organization ID` under the 'parent' field and plug it into this command to get the actual domain name of the organization:

```
$ gcloud organizations describe [ORGANIZATION_ID]
```

Once you have the name of the organization, find out who is the administrator of the organization so that you can give the user the necessary permissions.

As per the error you need permissions `orgpolicy.policies.create, orgpolicy.policies.delete, orgpolicy.policies.update, and orgpolicy.policy.get` which can be obtained by adding **Organization Policy Administrator**.

**[Organization Policy Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#orgpolicy.policyAdmin)** : Provides access to define what restrictions an organization wants to place on the configuration of cloud resources by setting Organization Policies.

Add the permission then try to allow external IPs for VM instances.

For more information  you can refer to the official document [Creating and managing organization policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/creating-managing-policies).

Comment: Is it possible for the administrator of "Acme corp" to configure things so that I can set policies for "Orange Octangulars" but not for other projects and not organization-wide policies?

Comment: @CrabMan - The easiest way to know is to review the ***Lowest-level resources where you can grant this role*** in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#organization-policy-roles). The lowest level that you can grant this role is Organization.

Comment: @CrabMan as JohnaHanley said it is that the lowest level that you can grant this role is Organization